# keep hearing usb plug unplug sound

Tags: windows-10, usb

[USBLogView logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnImN.png)

I used USBLogView to see what is getting connected and disconnected, here is what I get but I have no idea how to fix it

[Warning on device in device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/golph.png)

The warning is on my dac TOPPING DX3 PRO+, this is what I get when I unplug and plug it back :

[logs when unplug and plug dac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0OJY.png)

Comment: can you check Device Manager to see if any device there is showing warnings? Do you recognize the device USBLogView shows?

Comment: added the info @Esther

Comment: Do you own the device shown in USBLogView logs? Do you know what device it is, or is it completely random?

Comment: Have you checked the basics?  Have you tried a different USB cable? Do you have a ton of USB devices connected to the same USB Hub? Do you have any Windows notifications about a lack of USB resources being displayed?

Comment: The usb mass storage device ? No I don't know what device it is, I don't have any usb key or external hard drive

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have a usb hub and I don't know from which of my ports the problem is. No notification about lack of usb resources

Comment: @Roronoa_D._Law - Of course you have a USB Hub, it might be the header on your motherboard, but USB Hub (even if it's internal) has to exist. Your screenshots even prove this fact, but they don't include the properties of the device with the error, I assume the device doe snot stay connected long enough to do that?

Comment: yeah it gets disconnected instantly